# Show that neither x_0 nor x_1 are strict local minimum of a convex function

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let $f : S \rightarrow R$ be a convex function with two distinct local minima $x_0$ and $x_1$ with $f(x_0) = f(x_1)$. Show that neither $x_0$ nor $x_1$ are strict local minima.

How am I supposed to prove this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Just compute the value of the function at points between $x_0$ and $x_1$.

Comment: But I do not know the form of the function. How can I possibly find out the  value of the function at points between x0 and x1? But I know that the value of the function at points between x0 and x1 must be greater than f(x0)=f(x1).

Comment: What does convexity tell you about $f(\frac{x_0+x_1}2)$, for example?

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen // convexity tells you that f(x0+x1/2) must be less than or equal to 0.5*f(x0)+0.5*f(x1), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m := \min f = f(x_0) = f(x_1)$.
If $x_\lambda := (1-\lambda) x_0 + \lambda x_1$, $\lambda \in [0,1]$, then by convexity
$$
m \leq f(x_\lambda) \leq (1-\lambda) f(x_0) + \lambda f(x_1)
= (1-\lambda) m + \lambda m = m,
$$
i.e. $f(x_\lambda) = m$ for every $\lambda \in [0,1]$.
In other words, $f$ is constant on the interval with endpoints $x_0$ and $x_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But isn't f(x_lambda) less than or equal to m, instead of equal to m?

Comment: $m\leq f(x_\lambda) \leq m$ means that $f(x_\lambda) = m$.

Comment: Right. And the statements in your answer are enough to conclude that neither x nor y can be a strict local min? I just want to understand fully!